# When a SINGLE user opens their shared Doc, Prompt for authorisation?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have no idea how to attempt this, nor do I know if it's possible and I have no code to show. However, I shall be sending a doc created from a template to whoever filled a form in.

The script I want to run is to create a custom menu so they can click a button and send the doc to another person. This works. perfectly. The script even gets copied when the Doc is made from the template.

But the script that is copied won't run or even prompt me without manually going in the script editor and clicking run. the script will fail because it's supposed to run on open, but it gets auth.

I know you can't run shared scripts without user auth, unless it's published, That's not a route I'm taking. I just want the good old white google authorisation box to pop up as soon as they open the google doc they receive.

Any suggestions/ideas/code?

Cheers

Comment: Suggestion: Will this help? https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/addon-authorization

Comment: That... was fantastic. I'm going to give it a try, The bit that gives me faith and hope is this: "Note: Add-ons can't open sidebars or dialogs while executing in AuthMode.LIMITED. You can use **Menu Items** to open sidebars and dialogs since these run in AuthMode.FULL.
Running
When someone clicks one of an add-on's menu items, Apps Script first checks to see whether the user has installed the add-on, and prompts them to do so if not. "

Comment: @Srikanth You're a friggin genius. Much appreciation for showing me that. works perfectly. Can you post it as an answer so I can give you the rep you deserve.

Comment: Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the documentation at https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/addon-authorization. Add-on authorization is what you may need to implement.

Comment: Works great. Used editor add-ons. Tested it with a few colleagues. Many thanks again.